# How to rename generated table references?

Tags: jooq

I have two schemas in my database and both share tables with the same names.
In order to not have naming conflicts in generated code, I want to prefix all names with the appropriate schema name.

I made it work for class names by overriding `getJavaClassName` of `DefaultGeneratorStrategy` however I could not find a fitting override that is responsible for the table references in `tables.references.Tables.kt`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem by overriding `getJavaIdentifier` of `DefaultGeneratorStrategy` the following way:

```
override fun getJavaIdentifier(definition: Definition): String {
    if (definition is PostgresTableDefinition) {
        return "${definition.schema.name.toUppercaseSnakeCase()}_${super.getJavaIdentifier(definition)}"
    }

    return super.getJavaIdentifier(definition)
}
```